# Login screen lists "Recovery Key" but I am not using FileVault on my Mac Mini

Tags: filevault

Is this for my MacBook Pro perhaps? Both are M1 Macs (same Apple ID / iCloud account), the Mini is on Monterey while the MBP is now on Ventura. FV is enabled *only* on the MBP, but a Recovery Key shows on the login screen for both.